# Insert row for each userid for fields from other table

Tags: mysql, insert

I am learning MySQL and so don't know complex query. So need your expert help.

I have rc_userfields table with 4 fields, key and position which I already have. Now I want to add this 4 fields into `rc_profile` table. I want to add it for all userid. Means all 4 fields will be added for all userid.

**rc_userfields table**

Userid can be refereed from `rc_users` table
**rc_users table**

So final result would be something like below image
**rc_profile table**

Please refer below image for all three tables:

[image]

I know how can I insert manually with below code:

```
INSERT INTO `rc_profile` (`userid`, `keys`, `data`) VALUES
(1, 'myself', ''),
(1, 'position', ''),
(1, 'nickname', ''),
(1, 'blog', ''),
(2, 'myself', ''),
(2, 'position', ''),
(2, 'nickname', ''),
(2, 'blog', ''),
(3, 'myself', ''),
(3, 'position', ''),
(3, 'nickname', ''),
(3, 'blog', ''),
(4, 'myself', ''),
(4, 'position', ''),
(4, 'nickname', ''),
(4, 'blog', '');
```

Finally: I want to add all 4 fields keys from `rc_userfields` table to `rc_profile` table for every user in `rc_users` table

Comment: Yes because there was not proper information.. I am sorry if I did any mistake

Comment: Please don't do this in the future. If you don't get a proper answer then improve your question. Answer to comments and put that info in your question. If you do that your question will be pushed in the active questions queue and gets more attention.

Comment: I am really sorry! I will keep in mind and avoid such things. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need get the cartesian product of the two tables using `CROSS JOIN` and the result will be inserted on table `rc_profile`, eg.

```
INSERT  INTO rc_profile (userID, `keys`, data)
SELECT  a.userID, b.key, '' data
FROM    rc_users a CROSS JOIN rc_userfields b
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c95ad/2)

Comment: You are genius.. I was pulling my hair more than two hour to understand and make it work and you have done in 2 min.. Thanks a lot. Can you guide me or refer me some place where I can learn this type of advance query

Comment: this is not advance query, its just combining some sql stuffs `:)`.

Comment: I see but as I mentioned I am new to MySQL want to learn this type of tricks.. :) any site or videos?

Comment: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)